# MySQL information from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

`Select roleid , deity_level FROM default_jd_deity_role LIMIT 10;`

That gives the output:

```
+--------+-------------+
| roleid | deity_level |
+--------+-------------+
|   1024 |           1 |
|   1043 |          54 |
|   1056 |           1 |
|   1057 |          54 |
|   1072 |          54 |
|   1074 |          45 |
|   1075 |          36 |
|   1088 |          45 |
|   1089 |          45 |
|   1104 |          27 |
+--------+-------------+
```

Then I have this SQL:

`Select roleid , name FROM default_jd_ingame_roles LIMIT 22, 10`

That gives the following output:

```
+--------+---------+
| roleid | name    |
+--------+---------+
|   1024 | Hulu    |
|   1043 | Cookiez |
|   1056 | Sam     |
|   1057 | Sugar   |
|   1072 | Leah    |
|   1073 | Smexy   |
|   1074 | Bam!    |
|   1075 | Lexi    |
|   1088 | OneShot |
|   1089 | Demono  |
+--------+---------+
```

What I am trying to do is make deity_level add on to the second SQL Query like this:

```
+--------+---------+-------------+
| roleid | name    | deity_level |
+--------+---------+-------------+
|   1024 | Hulu    |           1 |
|   1043 | Cookiez |          54 |
|   1056 | Sam     |           1 |
|   1057 | Sugar   |          54 |
|   1072 | Leah    |          54 |
|   1073 | Smexy   |          45 |
|   1074 | Bam!    |          36 |
|   1075 | Lexi    |          45 |
|   1088 | OneShot |          45 |
|   1089 | Demono  |          27 |
+--------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Without specifying an order you can't rely on the results returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select a.roleid , a.deity_level, b.name
FROM default_jd_deity_role AS a
JOIN default_jd_ingame_roles AS b ON a.roleid=b.roleid
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT main.roleid, roles.name, main.deity_level
FROM default_jd_deity_role main
LEFT JOIN default_jd_ingame_roles roles ON main.roleid = roles.roleid
LIMIT 22, 10
```

I'll leave two nice tutorials to get you started on `JOINS`:

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a JOIN query:

```
SELECT igr.roleid , igr.name, dr.diety_level
FROM default_jd_ingame_roles igr
JOIN default_jd_deity_role dr ON dr.roleid = igr.roleid
```